# Why does everyone insist that Ruby be installed via rvm and not by compiling?

Tags: installation, ruby, rvm

I just installed Ruby on my 12.04 machine by compiling from the tarball file I got from the official Ruby site.

I want to know why doing that was a bad idea if I don't plan on using multiple versions of Ruby anytime in the future?

Answer (score 2):

What it boils down to is that ruby is a completely ecosystem, and it was not designed to have `sudo` in front of it for *anything*.

So it is recommended to use rvm (or rbenv or rbfu), since that way you should never have to use sudo.

Comment: I still haven't started using it. JUST installed it before posting haha. Can't seem to get the ruby command line working. I write 'ruby' and press enter and nothing happens. Was a lot easier in windows. Anyway, so you're saying I'll have to sudo everything?